# Обновление глобальной переменной во время обучения нейронной сети tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

В настоящий момент, изучаю вариационный автоэнкодер и пытаюсь проверить метод обучения с отжигом KL ошибки. Для данной операции необходимо равномерно увеличивать нормирующий коэффициент бета (β * KL). И я столкнулся с проблемой, у меня имеется код функции Callback

```
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
   
   def __init__(self, validation_data = ()):
       super(keras.callbacks.Callback, self).__init__()
       self.X_val, self.y_val = validation_data
       self.log_loss = []
       self.log_val_loss = []
       self.log_reconstruction_loss = []
       self.KL_loss = []
       
   def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
       global beta
#     Глобальная переменная для вычисления коэффциента beta
       beta = tf.cond(beta == 10, lambda: tf.math.reduce_min([beta,10]), lambda: tf.math.reduce_sum([beta,1]))
       tf.print(beta)
#         beta = tf.math.reduce_sum([beta,1]).numpy()
```

Данная функция вызывается в конце обучения. Для теста я увеличиваю значение beta таким способом

```
beta = tf.cond(beta == 10, lambda: tf.math.reduce_min([beta,10]), lambda: tf.math.reduce_sum([beta,1]))
```

Таким образом я могу контролировать, что значение увеличивается после окончания обучения.

Данная переменная используется в функции `def train_step(self, data):` для нормировки значения KL

```
#   Обучение нейронной сети
    @tf.function
    def train_step(self, data):
        global beta
        data_len = tf.shape(data)
        data_len = tf.cast(data_len[0], tf.float32)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
                )
            )
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + beta * kl_loss
            tf.print(beta)
```

Но возникает проблема, значение beta в функции `def train_step(self, data):` не увеличивается.
Как можно реализовать обновление значения при обучении.

Также, значение beta увеличивается, но не изменяется в функции `def train_step(self, data):`

Comment: Добавьте запись в стандартный логгер https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html Записывайте, чему равно ваше `beta` в обоих функциях до изменения, после изменения. Потом добавьте этот лог в вопрос. А может и сами поймёте по логу что не так. Может у вас этот коллбэк вообще не вызывается. По коду сложно что-то сказать, тем более он тут частично только.  Также укажите в вопросе, какое значение `beta` у вас сначала и как вы ожидаете что оно будет меняться. Если я правильно понимаю код, то `beta` должно расти пока оно меньше `10`, а потом перестать расти?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Данный коллбэк вызывается, потому что с его помощью отрисовываются графики. Также после того, когда останавливаешь обучение принудительно, значение beta меняется на то количество, сколько прошло эпох.

Comment: Вообще `global` лучше не использовать, по многим причинам. Но я не могу подсказать, как тут правильно без него обойтись. По вашему описанию похоже на то, что этот код выполняется многопоточно и тогда у каждого потока будет своя копия глобальных питоновских переменных. Вероятно поэтому работает не так, как вами задумано. Наверное нужно смотреть куда-то в сторону глобальных переменных самого TF: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_modules?hl=ru